# Core service fails because of partial trust.

Tags: core-service

I have encountered a problem when calling the core service. The error message is as follows:

> The WSHttpBinding with name WSHttpBinding failed validation because it contains a BindingElement with type System.ServiceModel.Channels.SymmetricSecurityBindingElement which is not supported in partial trust

Most solutions on the Internet seem to suggest changing the binding to use `basicHttpBinding`, but if I do that, I get a different message about the binding not supporting sessions.

How can I best approach solving or working around this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Indeed you can only use the SessionAwareCoreServiceClient with `wsHttp` or `NetTCP`, `basicHttp` does not support sessions.

If you do need to use Basic HTTP as the protocol, then you should use the `CoreServiceClient` class instead of the `SessionAwareCoreServiceClient`.

Can't you run your tool(s) from the server directly? (Avoiding the trust issue?)

Comment: No I can't, but I was wondering if a change in server config might make it work better.

Answer (score 3):

Please note in a Partial Trust environment, the WSHttpBinding is supported for Transport security mode only.

You can create custom binding to use but it must also complies to few restrictions like allowed transport binding elements will be HttpTransportBindingElement and HttpsTransportBindingElement, Bindings which are using reliable messaging, transactions etc. are not used and there are few other similar restriction which can be find on MSDN.

On this Stackflow question, few workarounds have been given, may be you can give a look to them:

[wcf-in-partial-trust-environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049244/wcf-in-partial-trust-environment)

I hope it helps.